# Android: when the animation is over

Tags: android, animation

I have made a `fromAlpha=1 toAlpha=0` animation to a view, but every time the animation is over the alpha turns to 1.

Is there a way to have the view stay in the last state of the animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the XML attribute [fillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3afillAfter) to keep the final state

Comment: Don't forget to set it on `set` tag, not `alpha`. Otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Animation does not move your view - only draws animation. If you want it to be in the place where animation ends(or save alpha changes) you should set AnimationListener and change your view position(or alpha) in OnAnimationEnd.